How to set a global condition to hide entities that are deleted
I want to set a condition on  all entites  to hide the ones that are deleted.
I could not find aa command in the Fluent Api to achieve this.
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BankAccountCurrencyType>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.IsDeleted == false || x.IsDeleted ==null );
}


I don't want to use this command for all entities

Check this extension method ApplyQueryFilter

So you want in your table an extra column to indicate that the record should not be shown for standard queries. Something that simulates that the record has been deleted, but with the possibility to undelete the record if requested.
This is quite standard behaviour in a database. The added column can be a Boolean IsDeleted, or a DateTime DeleteDate. The advantage of a DateTime value, is that you can periodically a process to really remove the records that are "deleted" long time ago.

Be aware that the DbSet<...> in your DbContext represent the Tables in your database. The non-virtual propertiess of the classes represent the columns in the tables. The virtual properties of the classes represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, etc.).

The extra column DeleteDate (or `IsDeleted) is a real column in your database. Hence it is a non-virtual property.
class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}

    // every Product is located in a Warehouse, using foreign key
    public int WarehouseId {get; set;}
    public virtual WareHouse WareHouse {get; set;}

    // the new Added property:
    public DateTime? DeleteDate {get; set;}
}

And the DbContext:
class OrderDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Warehouse> Warehouses {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Order> Orders {get; set;}
    ... // etc. One DbSet per table, except for junction tables
}

You want that if someone asks for products, that he doesn't get all Products, only those Products that have a null DeleteDate (or false IsDeleted).
This behaviour is not part of your database. If it was, no one could ever access the "deleted" records, not even the person who has the right to "undelete" records.
For extra behaviour, the Repository design pattern is used. The Repository is simply an extra class, that hides that your data is saved in a database, and that entity framework is used to communicate with the database.
The only thing that users of the Repository class (= software, not operators) know, is that you can put data in it, and that later you can retrieve the stored data, even after a restart of the software. For users there is no difference between storing in a database, an XML-file, or even the internet.
A typical Repository that uses entity framework:
class OrderRepository : IDisposable, ... // other interfaces, see later
{
    // the DbContext used by this Repository. Init in constructor
    private OrderDbContext OrderDbContext {get;}

    // constructors:
    public OrderRepository() : this(new OrderDbContext()) {}

    public OrderRepository(OrderDbContext orderDbContext{
    {
        if (orderDbContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(...);
        this.OrderDbContext = orderDbContext;
    }

    // TODO: implement IDisposable; Disposes this.OrderDbContext

    // access to the tables:
    public IQueryable<Product> Products => this.OrderDbContext.Products
        .Where(product => product.DeleteDate == null);

    public IQueryable<Customer> Customers => this.OrderDbContext.Customers
        .Where(customer => customer.DeleteDate ==  null);

    // ... etc, one IQueryable per accessible table.

    // TODO: methods to Add / Remove / Update items
}

Usage will be like this:
using (OrderRepository repository = new OrderRepository)
{
    // get all Products that are almost out of stock:
    int lowStockValue = 3;
    ICollection<Product> outOfStockProducts = repository.Products
        .Where(product => product.Stock <= lowStockValue)
        .ToList();

    // restock products that are almost out of stock:
    this.RestockLowStockProducts(outOfStockProducts);
}

Because the Repository is used to query, you don't get the deleted products.
Did you notice that for users there is no real difference between querying a DbContext or a Repository?
Interfaces for different users with different rights
To Add / Remove / Update items, you have to ask yourself: should everyone be able to do this? Should Everyone be able to remove a Customer, can everyone change the Price of a Product? Or should only certain types of users have the right to do this. For this, consider to create interfaces.
For instance, the interface for everyone: can query all non-sensitive data, cannot change anything:
interface IRepository
{
    // has all non-secret IQueryables
    IQueryable<Product> Products {get;}
    ...
}

Non-registered Customers, can query Products (descriptions, prices, stock), and they can register themselves. In that case, the software creates a
The interface for Registered Customers: can query Products, can create Orders, but can't change Prices, nor delete Products.
interface IRegisteredUser : IRepository
{
    int CreateOrder(int CustomerId);                            // returns OrderId
    int CreateOrderLine(int orderId, int productId, int count); // returns OrderLineId
    void UpdateOrderLine(int orderLineId, int count);           // count 0: remove OrderLine

    // etc. Everything you need to place an order
}

Note: communication with the Repository is low level. Software should already have checked for existing primary keys, non-negative count etc, existing customer, etc.
Some special users have rights to change Product Names, Product Prices, etc. And of course they can restock Products and delete Products
public ISuperUser : IRepository, ...  
{
    void UpdateProduct(Product product);
    void DeleteProduct(int productId);     // sets DeleteDate
    ...
}

I'm not sure if undeleting is something that a SuperUser should be able to do.
    Product UndeleteProduct(int productId)  // clears DeleteDate

A process is periodically run to remove all items that are deleted long time ago:
interface ICleanupRepository
{
    void Clean();
}

For in OrderRepository:
private TimeSpan MaxDeleteDate => TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
private DateTime DeleteThreshold => Datetime.Now - maxDeleteDate;
public void Clean()
{
    DateTime deleteThreshold = this.DeleteThreshold;
    ICollection<Product> productsDeletedLongAgo = this.OrderDbContext.Products
        .Where(product => product.DeleteDate != null && product.DeleteDate < deleteThreshold)
        .ToList();
    this.OrderDbContext.Products.RemoveRange(productsDeletedLongAgo);
    this.OrderDbContext.SaveChanges();
}

Finally, there is the group of users (Administrators?) who can do anything with the database: add / change / remove tables, etc. These users are the only ones that use the OrderDbContext directly.
class OrderRepository : IUser, IRegisteredUser, ISuperUser, ...
{
    ...
}

Use the factory design pattern to give everyone the interface he needs. I won't describe safety here (user identification, logon, etc)
class RepositoryFactory
{
    public IUser CreateUserRepository()
    {
        return (IUser) new OrderRepository();
    }

    public IRegisteredUser CreateRegisteredUserRepository(int userId)
    {
         OrderRepository repository = new OrderRepository();
         // check userId: is it a registered user?
         if (userIdOk) return repository;
    }

    // etc. for all types of users.
}

Note that this is not full proof (full proof?). Malicious software can type cast to the incorrect type of user. If the software that uses the repository can be trusted, there is no need to prevent this. However, if you plan to distribute the access to others who you can't trust, it might be better to create a different repository for different types of users.
Of course you already had this problem when the software was using the DbContext directly.
